# Share sequence from 2 user in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

In database server Postgres 9.x or Postgres 10.x can I share the same sequence from 2 user?

For example in the same database dbTest there are 2 schemas

1. userA is schema owner schemaA with a sequenceA
2. userB is schema owner schemaB

Can userB use sequenceA sequence?
What are the permits to be given?

After solution there is the situation:

```
userA: select nextval('sequenceA');
userB: select nextval('schemaA.sequenceA');
```

If I also want for the userB:
select nextval('sequenceA');

Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you talking about different databases or different schemas (this is not MySQL)?

Comment: Same database with different schemas.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of "schema" and "db" in the description is a bit hard to follow, but the above only works inside the same database.

---

The following will only work across schemas (in the same database).

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) you need to grant the USAGE privilege for the sequence:

```
grant usage on sequence schema_a.sequencea to userb;
```

If you want to allow `userb` to update the current value (via `setval()`) you also need to grant the `update` privilege.

Comment: You also need a privilege on the sequence.